# How to use ActionInterface insted of Deprecated Action class

Tags: magento2, action, actioninterface

I start learning magneto 2. I give it a try with Max Pronko's videos. Figure out some of the codes that are outdated, deprecated.
Here is my controller. Any suggestion on how to use ActionInterface here.

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Isuru\FirstPage\Controller\Page;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class View extends Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var Json $jsonResult */
        $jsonResult = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
        $jsonResult->setData([
            'message' => 'First Page'
        ]);
        return $jsonResult;ActionInterface
    }
}
```

[image]

[image: strong text]

Comment: I guess <a href="https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/routing.html#action-class">this link</a> can help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The class `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action` is deprecated in the latest version of the Magento. Instead of you should use the `GET` or `POST` interface as per your request type

1. `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface`
2. `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface`

These both interface extends `\Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface`

**So your sample controller should look like this**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;


class Index implements HttpGetActionInterface
{
    public function execute()
    {
        // code ..
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can we use ActionInterface directly?

Comment: Yes, we can use but as per Magento standard, we should use the GET to POST action interface instead of direct use.

Comment: Got it and working. Thanks